# How to expose C++ functions to a lua script?

Tags: c++, function, lua

I just successfully created an lua project. (A simple code that runs an lua script so far.)
But how would I make a c++ function and a c++ variable available for the lua script now?

As an example:

```
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

and

```
float myFloatValue = 6.0
```

I'm very new to c++ so I really hope that it won't be too complicated. Here is the code I got so far btw:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    lua_State* luaInt;
    luaInt = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs (luaInt);
    luaL_dofile (luaInt, "abc.lua");
    lua_close(luaInt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll go with John Zwinck's answer as experience has proven to me that using Lua all by itself is a pain in the butt. But, if you want to know the answer check the rest.

For registering C/C++ functions you need to first make your function look like a standard C function pattern which Lua provides:

```
extern "C" int MyFunc(lua_State* L)
{
  int a = lua_tointeger(L, 1); // First argument
  int b = lua_tointeger(L, 2); // Second argument
  int result = a + b;

  lua_pushinteger(L, result);

  return 1; // Count of returned values
}
```

Every function that needs to be registered in Lua should follow this pattern. Return type of `int`, single parameter of `lua_State* L`. And count of returned values.

Then, you need to register it in Lua's register table so you can expose it to your script's context:

```
lua_register(L, "MyFunc", MyFunc);
```

For registering simple variables you can write this:

```
lua_pushinteger(L, 10);
lua_setglobal(L, "MyVar");
```

After that, you're able to call your function from a Lua script. Keep in mind that you should register all of your objects before running any script with that specific Lua state that you've used to register them.

In Lua:

```
print(MyFunc(10, MyVar))
```

Result:

20

Comment: `MyFunc` needs to be `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Simple Yes, I assumed Lua is included with `extern "C"` so I didn't mention it.

Comment: that's precisely why `MyFunc` needs to be `extern "C"`. `lua_CFunction` is a pointer to function with C linkage but `MyFunc` has C++ linkage. The standard says these are two distinct types so it shouldn't compile (although most mainstream compilers erroneously accept it).

Comment: Thank you so much for that! This is incredibly helpful.
I'm wondering if you can tell me why I get about 30 warnings?
http://pastebin.com/KpTYvPDZ

Comment: @Forivin You're using managed C++ and I think that's the reason. I haven't worked with C++ CLI and I don't know if Lua is compatibile with managed C++. Make an empty Win32 project and then test your code.

Comment: The weird thing is, that my code worked fine. It just feels super wrong and unclean with all these messages. 
I don't how how I would start with an empty Win32 project.
I used the precompiled header option. Then I did the same thing I did with my last project (besides I had to add Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)). I really don't know much about c++ and visual studio 10..  
However I still get these warning messages. :(  
  
Btw, can I really make c++ functions available for lua? I thought that extern "C" would mean that you include C-code in a C++ project?

Comment: @Forivin Well, warnings are related to different things or a single thing that is harmful. Answering this question in here is not allowed since community rules are clear and besides the topic is about something else. Exposing functions to Lua is what this answer all about. `extern "C"` means using C conventions to compile that code and it's not related to your current question.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing it using the Lua C API, I suggest using [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html).

Luabind is a reasonably high-level library specifically built to expose C++ classes and functions to Lua.  Without using the Lua C API functions, without manipulating the Lua stack, etc.  It's inspired by Boost Python, so if you learn one you'll mostly understand the other.

Comment: or [LuaBridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html) just in case the author doesn't want to use Boost.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov that site is now dead, appears to be at https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge now